# Convert tuples to json using rdf4j

Tags: java, json, sparql, rdf4j

The problem is the following: When parsing a sparql query, I get simplified ast and I need to pass it to a third-party library for further processing, but the functionality out of the box (rdf4j) does not allow transferring ast in a machine-readable format, only tex, I would like to receive in json format.

```
        StringBuilder qb = new StringBuilder();
        qb.append("    PREFIX has_vaccine_allergen: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/VO_0000531>\n" +
                "    PREFIX chicken_egg_protein_allergen: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/VO_0000912>   \n" +
                "    SELECT distinct ?vaccine_label ?vaccine \n" +
                "    FROM <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/merged/VO>\n" +
                "    WHERE {\n" +
                "        ?vaccine rdfs:label ?vaccine_label .\n" +
                "        ?vaccine rdfs:subClassOf ?vaccine_restriction .\n" +
                "        ?vaccine_restriction owl:onProperty has_vaccine_allergen:; owl:someValuesFrom chicken_egg_protein_allergen: .\n" +
                "\t}");
        SPARQLParser parser = new SPARQLParser();

        ParsedTupleQuery q = (ParsedTupleQuery)parser.parseQuery(qb.toString(), null);
        TupleExpr te = q.getTupleExpr();
        System.out.println(te);
```

Result of code execution:

```
SelectQuery
[PrefixDecl (prefix=has_vaccine_allergen), PrefixDecl (prefix=chicken_egg_protein_allergen), SelectQuery]
Distinct
   Projection
      ProjectionElemList
         ProjectionElem "vaccine_label"
         ProjectionElem "vaccine"
      Join
         Join
            Join
               StatementPattern
                  Var (name=vaccine)
                  Var (name=_const_9285ccfc_uri, value=http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label, anonymous)
                  Var (name=vaccine_label)
               StatementPattern
                  Var (name=vaccine)
                  Var (name=_const_4592be07_uri, value=http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf, anonymous)
                  Var (name=vaccine_restriction)
            StatementPattern
               Var (name=vaccine_restriction)
               Var (name=_const_a509c4e0_uri, value=http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#onProperty, anonymous)
               Var (name=_const_3319983d_uri, value=http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/VO_0000531, anonymous)
         StatementPattern
            Var (name=vaccine_restriction)
            Var (name=_const_6539d60c_uri, value=http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#someValuesFrom, anonymous)
            Var (name=_const_3319a704_uri, value=http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/VO_0000912, anonymous)
```

I need get that to json format

Comment: So? then traverse the query algebra tree and create a Json object in the way you need in the 3rd party lib. Hint: use the visitor pattern and implement a `QueryModelVisitor` or even better `AbstractQueryModelVisitor`

Comment: Out of curiosity: what exactly do you plan to do with the query once you've converted it to JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: the `TupleExpr` object (and the tree underneath it) is not the Abstract Syntax Tree (AST), but instead is RDF4J's query algebra model. If you wish to work directly on the AST of a SPARQL query, you can use [`SyntaxTreeBuilder.parseQuery(queryString)`](http://docs.rdf4j.org/javadoc/latest/index.html?org/eclipse/rdf4j/query/parser/sparql/ast/SyntaxTreeBuilder.html) to receive the actual AST. That said, doing query re-processing on either AST or algebra model can work, it depends a bit on what exactly your output is supposed to do which one is the best choice.

For either AST or query algebra model, RDF4J has abstract [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example) implementations that you can freely extend for your own needs. For AST trees, [`AbstractASTVisitor`](http://docs.rdf4j.org/javadoc/latest/index.html?org/eclipse/rdf4j/query/parser/sparql/AbstractASTVisitor.html) is a good starting point (make sure you pick the right one, RDF4J has two: one for SeRQL, one for SPARQL). For query algebra models, the place to start is [`AbstractQueryModelVisitor`](http://docs.rdf4j.org/javadoc/latest/index.html?org/eclipse/rdf4j/query/algebra/helpers/AbstractQueryModelVisitor.html). There's tons of examples of implementations of either in the RDF4J code base itself. The typical pattern is that you override the `meet` methods where you want to define your own behavior, taking care to call `super.meet()` at the end when you're processing a node that is not a leaf.

Comment: is SyntaxTreeBuilder mostly for only visiting the AST? if I wanted to parse a SPARQL query, modify a node in the AST, and then serialize back to a SPARQL query string, does RDF4J make this straightforward? Or do I need to consider using another interface, such as the algebra model, instead?